# List field manipulation based on rules

Tags: list, development, column, spfield, codebehind

he following situation:

I have got list (List A) with the following fields.

- Field A ->String
- Field B-> String
- Field C →LookUp to another list
- Field D → Calculated field
- Field E

On creating or updating a new item I would like to read out the value of Field D and if it is a certain value set Field A to another value and so on:

IF(Field D == “valueX”)
    Field A = “Hello”;

else if (Field E.isEmpty())
    Field C = “Hello”;

So what I would like to do is simple manipulation on list columns. Normally I would implement this logic in an EventHandler or sometimes with javascript. The issue I have with EventHandler is the deployment. Writing code every time I want to manipulate a list item is not where I want to go.

I would rather like to do the manipulation maybe in a Sharepoint 2010 workflow. The issue with Sharepoint Designer Workflow is that I can not access and manipulate all kind of Sharepoint fileds. With code I could do more.

So I'm looking for a solution in between. Let's say there is a List A and a configuration List for List A(List_A_config). In List_A_config I define my rules(IF(Field D == “valueX”),...) Than I would like to start a workflow when ever I'm updating or creating an item in List A, which calles the rules I have defined in  List_A_config and validates the item accoriding to the the rules in List_A_config.

For this solution I would need a Framework. Does anybody know such a Framework or something similar to achieve my goals? Before I start implementing my idea I would like to get a feedback

Comment: For this, I'd either use InfoPath and set up riles like that or hook into the PresaveAction using jQuery.

Comment: To hook into PresaveAction with jQuery is an option